# Is there any indicator to know OleDbDataAdapter has got records or not based on supplied query?

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledbdataadapter

I am having textbox where user can enter product id and based on that populate gridview.I have all the products in my excel file
and using OleDbConnection and `OleDbDataAdapter` I fill my datatable which is binded with `gridview using BindingSource`.

Is it possible to get some indication product is found or not(null or count check) in OleDbDataAdapter before filling datatable?

Code :

```
string fieldSelector = "[ProductID], [ProductName],[MRP]";
string query = $"SELECT {fieldSelector} FROM [{sheetName}$A1:Q15535] WHERE [ProductID] = {Convert.ToInt32(txtProductId.Text)}";
using (OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls))
{
     oda.Fill(dtProductList);//dtProductList global variable at winform level
}
```

Lets say I have already added 2 products and now I enter product which is not found in excel then again i have to may be look inside datatable and based on that show message to user that "Product is not found".

Comment: You can't know how many rows a query will return before actually executing that query. Why do you want to know the number of rows in advance? Why not just check the number of rows in the DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make an [OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) call to find the count of records returned. You may have to change fieldSelector to "count(*)" when using ExecuteScalar